# Debugging objc4 (532.2) on OS X 10.9

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to get ***objc4-532.2*** to work on Mavericks.

(First of all, I tried to compile the latest version of objc4 (objc4-551.1).
This fails due ***os/lock_private.h*** is missing (***objc-os.h***). Maybe anyone knows how to solve this issue?)

Back to topic:

To successfully build ***objc4-532.2*** I need to link against the frameworks which are based
on OS X 10.8.
So I configured the Xcode project to use OS X 10.8 SDKs for ***Base SDK*** and ***OS X Deployment Target***.

This works, and I can compile and link a simple console based C program (Xcode template).

However when I try to link this program against Foundation and debug it, it miserably fails with the following error:

> ***dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_debug_taggedpointer_mask   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>   Expected in:
>   /Users/manu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/objc-dtrsexfveobodwdnwlpknyyiekpe/Build/Products/Debug/libobjc.A.dylib
>   in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation***

The symbol ***_objc_debug_taggedpointer_mask*** was first introduced in ***objc4-551.1*** (latest runtime) and all 10.9 Frameworks needs to access this symbol (at least in debug mode).

Example:

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C
$ grep objc_debug_taggedpointer_mask Foundation
Binary file Foundation matches
```

A Framework based on 10.8 doesn't contain such a symbol.

Since my project is configured to use 10.8 SDKs this error should not occur?!
So, what's the missing point?

Thanks!

Comment: The point of the linker error is that if you're going to compile one, you'll have to compile all others linking against it.  Your version of objc may be older, but CoreFoundation was linked against the latest one.

Comment: @leunam Did you finally find lock_private.h? I'm trying to build libdispatch and I have the same missing file...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem: the symbol of objc_debug_taggedpointer_mask was imported into runtime after mac os x 10.9, so you need to add the new tags into the 532.2's code to make it compatible with os x 10.9's foundation and other frameworks.

Here is my working directory:

> https://github.com/Jeswang/objc4-532.2

Answer (score 0):

> (First of all, I tried to compile the latest version of objc4
>   (objc4-551.1). This fails due os/lock_private.h is missing
>   (objc-os.h). Maybe anyone knows how to solve this issue?)

The best solution I could find is to manually scrape together the header files as described here:
http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2011/how_to_build_libobjc_for_os_x.html

The closest thing to `os/lock_private.h` that I have found is `private/tsd_private.h` from the libpthread project:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-105.40.1/private/tsd_private.h

**Edit**
I have also found this:
https://github.com/samdmarshall/OSXPrivateSDK